# iDEAL Payment Integration

Tags: php, mysql

Need help to integrate iDEAL payment integration with PHP/MySQL.

Are there any tutorials or references?

Comment: [link](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/ideal-payment-integration/). This may help

Comment: Please share with us which broker you are using. Are you working directly with a bank? Or do you use a separate payment provider?

Comment: Don't know exactly what it is ? I was expecting It would be like paypal. But it is bit different. I am having customer ID provided by ING bank and whatever the transaction takes place amount should be credited on that customer ID using iDEAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following links. It may help you :

[iDEAL help.](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/ideal-payment-integration/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how iDEAL payments work but for most other payment methods around the world, you need to find a PSP (Payment Service Provider) who will sit in between you and the system. There is more info here: [iDEAL](http://www.ideal.nl/acceptant/?s=hoe&lang=eng-GB)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably contact them and they should give you an integration manual.

Normally such vendors either work through a http form submit or some kind of backend integration. Both are usually technology neutral.